# Write a Struct to Binary File in C

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

I am trying to write the contents of a struct into a binary file in C.

The Struct looks like:

```
typedef struct fileData fileData;
struct fileData {
    uint8_t data1;
    uint8_t data2;
    uint8_t data3;
}
```

I am trying to get these 3 data pieces to write to the header of the binary file (each as 1 byte).

```
fileData* fileWriting;
fileWriting->data1 = 10;
fileWriting->data2 = 20;
fileWriting->data3 = 30;
```

Code to write to file:

```
FILE * outputFile = fopen("test.bin","wb");
fwrite(&fileWriting->data1,1,1, outputFile);
fwrite(&fileWriting->data2,1,1, outputFile);
fwrite(&fileWriting->data3,1,1, outputFile);
fclose(outputFile);
```

However, this is giving errors (i.e. bus:10). What is wrong/is there a better way?

Comment: You should specify what errors you get...

Comment: Your second code snippet invokes *undefined behavior*. `fileWriting` doesn't point to determinate data, yet you're dereferencing it.

Comment: it gives a bus error: 10

Comment: `fileData* fileWriting;` --> `fileData* fileWriting = malloc(sizeof(*fileWriting));` or just use `fileData fileWriting; fileWriting.data1 = 10;`

Comment: Make sure to enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY -- solved the issue.